# Invoke an Outlook compose from a website?

Tags: javascript, templates, outlook, message

I am trying to see if there is any way to invoke/start Outlook compose from a website (html/javascript). In additional, it would need to use a template.

For example:
I click on a button on a web page, it will start the Outlook compose message window and have a bunch of stuff in the body of the message ready (including a signature image).

I know that there is `<a href="mailto:...."/>` but that doesn't allow images in the body (since it only takes a string for the body parameter).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks
:)

Comment: P.S. this just need to work on IE and Outlook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything other than `mailto`: would be a security risk. Browsers should never launch apps.

Comment: Came here to say this. While it would be nice to be able to write a web page that could do this, there are just too many ways it could and would be exploited, so it's not possible. Instead, consider using mailto:address?body=etc&subject=alsoEtc. You might be able to simply download them a pre-filled out Outlook template, but I'm not sure how you'd then get it to send correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this only need to be used on IE and Outlook.  So I found that there is a MailItem ActiveXObject (Outlook.Application) which allows me to add (via Javascript) an HTML body that can embed images. But I am not getting the images to show up in the `<img src=".../>` tags.

Comment: Well, I was able to do it via something like: `<img src='file:///C:/batman.png'/>Na na na na...` and `<img src='http://www.google.com/logos/2011/houdini11-hp.jpg'/>poof...`

Comment: You can't use a file reference since the file path will not be available to others. You can post images using a URL though.

Answer (score 1):

If the user has Outlook as default email client you can use a [mailto](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_a_mailto_link/) link, don't see any other way right out of the box.